# custom header using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am looking to create a layout as follows in LaTeX. I tried using `fancyhdr` but I am unable to get it right.

```
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=0.75in]{translogo}} 
\chead{\parbox{5cm}{INTEROFFICE   MEMORANDUM \\ Document Name \\}}
\rhead{\parbox{5cm}{ \today \\ \\ TOP \\ Confidential document \\}}
```

This is what it should look like:

```
___________________________________________________________________________
|        |          INTEROFFICE MEMO                      | DATE          | 
|LOGO    |           DOCUMENT NAME                        | Number        |
|        |                                                |               |
___________________________________________________________________________

blah ...............
\lipsum

____________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses [`fancyhdr`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr) combined with the [`geometry`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry) package, and using the optional arguments of the `parbox` command.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,
                        headheight=2in,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\lhead{\parbox[b][.75in][t]{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.75in]{translogo}}} 
\chead{\parbox[b][.75in][t]{5cm}{INTEROFFICE   MEMO \\ Document Name}}
\rhead{\parbox[b][.75in][t]{4cm}{ \today \\ \\ TOP \\ Confidential document}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You can use a simple `\fbox` to get a box around each element

```
\lhead{\fbox{\parbox[b][.75in][t]{4cm}{\includegraphics[height=0.75in,width=4cm]{translogo}}}} 
\chead{\fbox{\parbox[b][.75in][t]{5cm}{INTEROFFICE   MEMO \\ Document Name}}}
\rhead{\fbox{\parbox[b][.75in][t]{4cm}{ \today \\ \\ TOP \\ Confidential document}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks CMH. But I want bounding boxes around each header element.    Like 3 column table with multiple rows in them.

Comment: @avlsi see the update :)

Comment: thanks for the update. But I want the fbox to be continuous so that it looks like 3 columns. First col - 3cm , second col - 7 cm and third col - 5 cm. I tried to plugin the same  values into the fbox but the output was not as expected. And also is the a way to centre justify text in chead{}.

Comment: I have solved the centre justification using center environment but unable to make the three cols.